# Check IF Result from Select Query with Async NodejS in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, promise, node-mysql

I've got the following code in NodeJS using an Async/Promises wrapper for Mysql ;

```
row_c = await db.query( 'SELECT tagid FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?', [tag1] );
```

How do I now check if there is a result for an IF statement?

I tried;

```
   if (row_c.tagid){
   ///some code
    }
```

But it's not picking up the conditional. How do I check if the query returned a row?

Comment: afaik, the `db.query` returns a list. You need to check `if (row_c.length)`

Comment: That worked! can you please add as answer and I will select it.  if (row_c.length > 0){}

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.query` returns an array of rows. You can do the following:

```js
row_c = await db.query( 'SELECT tagid FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?', [tag1] );

if (row_c.length) {
  // if data is returned
  console.log(row_c);
}
```